# user profile photos not appearing in search results even after full sync

Tags: search, user-profile, active-directory, search-results

I imported user photos to the thumbnailPhoto Active Directory attribute. I ran a full user profile synchronization. Then, I ran the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore PowerShell command as described [here](http://sharepointadam.com/2010/11/18/import-user-profile-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2010/). Also, ["show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page" is checked.](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/people-search-result-doesnt-have-images-in-sharepoint-2010/)

The photos appear in the user profiles and the organization browser, but not in the People Search results.

I'm running SharePoint Enterprise 2010 with the February 2012 CU.

How can I make the photos appear in the search results?

Comment: Have you checked Managed Properties (Groups > People > PictureUrl) to see if it is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. To clarify for anyone who may not know where the setting is, it's in application management > manage service applications > search service application > metadata properties > categories > people > people:pictureurl

Comment: @Hugh Wood You should turn your comment into an answer so that LCountee can accept it and so that people will see that an accepted solution has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment,

Go to Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Service Applications > Search Service Application

Click Managed Properties and go to Groups > People > people:pictureurl and configure in here.